# compiler error for shared_ptr in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, shared-ptr

Converting a project from Codeblocks to Visual Studio I encountered this puzzling error from the compiler:

```
Error   4   error C2228: left of '.swap' must have class/struct/union
shared_ptr.hpp

Error   3   error C2440: '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from
'boost::shared_ptr<T>' to 'boost::shared_ptr<T>' shared_ptr.hpp 384
```

Here's the code in question in boost's shared_ptr.hpp

```
template<class Y>
shared_ptr & operator=( shared_ptr<Y> && r ) // never throws
{
    this_type( static_cast< shared_ptr<Y> && >( r ) ).swap( *this );
    return *this;
}
```

I set up a similar but less complicated project and did not get the same error.

Comment: Could you provide the code where you assign an r-value to a shared_ptr of some sort, and provide the types involved.

Comment: shared_ptr is used all over the place, I'll check through all assignments to see if I made a mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably try to swap two `shared_ptr` of incompatible types. Make sure that the two `shared_ptr` point to objects of the same/convertible type.